# Finding the index from divide and conquer approach

Tags: python, divide-and-conquer

Im practicing using divide and conquer approach using the practice from
https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iii/

```
def calcchanges(price):
    changes = []
    for i in range(len(price)-1):
        delta = round(price[i+1] - price[i],3)
        changes.append(delta)
    return changes

def MSSDAC(A, low=0, high=None):
    if high==None:
        high = len(A)-1

    if low==high:
        if A[low]>0:
            return A[low]
        else:
            return 0
    mid = (low+high)//2
    maxleft = MSSDAC(A, low, mid)
    maxright = MSSDAC(A, mid+1, high)
    maxleft2center = left2center = 0
    for i in range(mid, low-1, -1):
        left2center += A[i]
        maxleft2center = max(left2center, maxleft2center)
    maxright2center = right2center = 0
    for i in range(mid+1, high+1):
        right2center += A[i]
        maxright2center = max(right2center, maxright2center)
    return max(maxleft, maxright, maxleft2center+maxright2center)

#This code is only focusing on 1 transaction
""" Example 2
Input: prices = [1,2,3,4,5]
Output: 4
Explanation: Buy on day 1 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4.
Note that you cannot buy on day 1, buy on day 2 and sell them later, as you are engaging multiple transactions at the same time. You must sell before buying again.
"""
prices = [1,2,3,4,5]
changes = calcchanges(prices)
maxprofit = MSSDAC(changes)
print(maxprofit)
```

My question would be, is it possible to get the day?, Buy on day 1 and sell on day 5?

By using divide and conquer I split the list recursively. Thus i'm kinda lost how to track the index.

Comment: FIRST, you need to preprocess that data to create a cumulative sum.  What you have there is the daily swing, NOT the closing value.  From your description, you want the closing value.  `-20` and `-11` do not appear in your array at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, `A.index(value)` will give the first location of a given value.  You don't say what you want to do if there is more than one.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your reply! I actually have 2 more list list of the closing value, and the dates. Youre right! This A list is generated from another function that creates the daily swing. Basically im trying to get the index in order to get the dates. When to buy, and when to sell.. Any suggestion where should i start?

Comment: I told you where to start.  The `index` method will tell you which index contains a given value.  I don't understand why you're using a quicksort for this.  `max` and `min` will give you the high and low close values.

Comment: @TimRoberts im practicing divide and conquer approach for this method. but then i realized that this method breaks down my list recursively. Thus, i cant track my index anymore. Is it impossible to get the index using this approach then?

Comment: It's not impossible, it just means you have to track the index numbers yourself.  Instead of using `max(left2center,maxleft2center)`, you'd need to use `if left2center > maxleft2Center`, and then save the index of the new maximum.